# send inline html with mailx (Heirloom mailx 12.4)

Tags: smtp, redhat, content-type, rhel6, mailx

I am trying (to no avail) to send inline html with mailx utility (Heirloom mailx 12.4). Email is being sent in plain text.

- My mailx version does not support -a for header (used for attachments
  instead)
- As non root user, options such as: configuring sendmail for
  smtp or installing 3rd party like mutt arent available
- Linux Distro: RHEL 6 (Santiago)

EDIT: After a few hours I found this post which has allowed to go one step further. Email is now sent in HTML but contains header in text.
Script below:

```
mailx -v -S smtp=SERVER -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject v1\nContent-Type: text/html\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Disposition: inline")" -r FROM TO < htmlmail.txt
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384536/html-email-from-heirloom-mailx-on-linux

[image: Here's what I mean by "Headers are pushed down into body"]

Comment: What do you mean by "contains header in text"?

Comment: Hi @tripleee. Thanks for the quick answer. I mean that this script ends up sending an html email but the headers are included inline with the body it outputs as such: Content-Disposition: inline Message-ID: <5e0504ca.ACB5d8VMw0pjPORw%xxx@domain.com> User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Cher Alassane Sarr.

Votre mot de passe zuuluPay a bien été réinitialisé.
Vous pouvez désormais accéder à votre compte avec le numéro de portable...

Comment: You mean the Subject and MIME-Version headers are handled correctly but the remainder is pushed down into the body?

Comment: @tripleee. That's correct. See image above of email received: headers are pushed down into body. Also note that MIME-TYPE text/html specified in script has been somehow replaced by text/plain when displayed in webmail (eventhough it is correctly displayed in html). Any suggestion: to remove header from email content?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with Heirloom `mailx` to suggest anything other than replacing it with a simpler client which gives you control over these things. Perhaps you could install `ssmtp` if you can't install `sendmarl`? The full message source woud be more useful than an image. I can *speculate* that needlessly adding `MIME-Version:` and `Content-Disposition:` is what breaks it but this whole approach is brittle anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, permissions aren't sufficient enough to install third party tool like ssmtp.

Comment: @tripleee: I understand your point about MIME-VERSION or CONTENT-DISPOSITION but the odd thing is that removing either one of them would cause email to be sent in plain/text agan.

Comment: I can verify that Heirloom `mailx` 12.5 on Debian Jessie always adds an explicit `Content-Type: text/plain` header which (for some MTAs) will override whatever you pass in as ostensibly part of the `Subject:` header. For what it's worth, Debian Stretch comes with Heirloom `mailx` 14.8 which does not behave like this.

Comment: I can suggest replacing `mailx` with a simple Python or Perl script. Even Python 2.x comes with a quite capable `smtplib` which should allow you to replace `mailx` with something more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

**It's all about the right setup of postfix:**

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

add this:

```
smtp_mime_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_mime_header_checks.pcre
```

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/smtp_mime_header_checks.pcre
```

add this:

```
/^Content-Type:/  REPLACE Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
/^Content-Transfer-Encoding:/ REPLACE Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

```
sudo nano restart postfix
```